# How to install Xcode using Xcode8.3.2.bin

Tags: xcode8

My mac does not have internet connection so that I have to download a Xcode 8.3.2.bin from https://mac-torrent-download.net/application/apple/xcode-8-3-2-8e2002/ on Windows machine.

Now I got Xcode8.3.2.bin file on Mac. How do i install xcode?

I use archive utility app to open xcode 8.3.2.bin and got xcode8.3.2.bin.cpgz.
what should i do next?

Comment: I've same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download zip file from apple website.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded The file too.. after trying everything human possible, the Holy Spirit told me to simply rename the file to .xip rather than the .bin and that worked perfectly.